# Form Builder Not updaing details

Tags: permissions, formbuilder

I have created a form in Form builder to enable a logged in user to update some details we have stored for them (their Gift Aid status).
This displays via a short code in  a wordpress page  ([civicrm component="afform" name="afformGiftAid" hijack="0"])

If I am logged in as an administrator it updated the record. If I am logged in as a "general user" it does not update the record. I am guessing this is a permission issue -  Can anyone  advise what permissions need to used in Civi/ Wordpress to ensure the record gets updated -  I have tried a few and no success.

We are getting the following errors in the Log files

[debug] Silently ignoring exception in Afform processGenericEntity call: Authorization failed
[debug] $API Request Authorization failed = #0 /.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(153): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("API Request Authorization failed", TRUE)

Wordpress  6.4.1 CivCRM 5.65.2

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing a similar issue, the difference for me is I have a public facing form that allows non-logged in users to submit the form to create individuals in Civi. Located on the Form Settings tab, I had the Form's Permission set to *Generic: Allow all users (including anonymous)* but experienced the same Authorization Failed error.

My solution was to change each of the form's "entities" *Security* from **User-Based** to **Form-Based** which then used the Form's Permissions mentioned above. To find this setting:

1. Edit your form and find the Form Settings tab (should be selected by default).
2. Each of the tabs to the right is what I'm calling an "entity". You may only have one or many depending on your form.
3. On each of these tabs, about half way down, directly under the *Options* header is the **Security** drop down. This is what I changed to Form-Based.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for that -  Have parked it for now, but will take alook at that option when I get a moment!